# What does “lésion” mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, santé-et-médecine

I would like to know the precise meaning of the word “*lésion*”. I’ve seen it associated with the word “brain” in some sentences, which led me to think it sometimes means “tumor” but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lésion" means something going wrong (damage) with any biological tissue causing it not to functional normally. It's used with brain, muscles, skin or any tissue that lives.

Answer (score 4):

“*Lésion*” generally means “lesion” or ”wound”, but as far as I know, never “tumor”.

“*Lésion*” can be associated with the word “*cerveau*” when speaking of “*[lésion cérébrale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%E9sion_c%E9r%E9brale)*”, which means (quite approximately, I’m no doctor) “[brain damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_damage)”.